# jQuery AJAX call based on drop-down doesn't return any response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with multiple drop-downs and need to make a ajax call to check if there is a match based on selection of 2 different drop-downs.

First there is Program drop-down and then Company drop-down. There is a match for each program/company, so when a programValue is selected, if the user selects a company that's not associated with the program, I need to just show a warning message that it doesn't match, but they can still go ahead and submit it.

```
    $('#CompanySelect').change(function() {
    var ProgramValue = $("#Program").val();
    var sCompany = $("##CompanySelect").val();
    $.ajax({
             url: 'checkProgram.cfm',
             type: 'post',
             data: {Program:ProgramValue, Company:sCompany},
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);  
        }
     });
```

so checkProgram.cfm runs couple of queries to match company with program and passes true/false as response.

```
<cfif bMatch>
    <cfset ajaxResponse = true>
<cfelse>
    <cfset ajaxResponse = false>
</cfif>

<cfoutput>#SerializeJson(ajaxResponse)#</cfoutput>
```

However, when I do console.log(data), it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No "amazing help" suggest itself to me to offer you. However, two thoughts.

1. when ajax doesn't return anything, it's usually the calling script isn't returning anything. So, you might also add an .error return handler on your ajax call (should ALWAYS have one anyway).
2. The "##" selectors look a little strange to me. :) I have seen code that does that before, but it's very rare. Is that what you really meant?

Comment: Yes ## were from my code, because I was doing a cfoutput and it requires ##, however, I removed it just to avoid that issue here.  When I tested the calling script, it didn't return true and false.

Comment: Adding the error handler helped me figure out the issue, thanks

Comment: Coolness. As a deeply ingrained habit, I always put in error trappers of every type I can imagine, and then hope they never fire! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `##` selectors are incorrect. Should only have one `#` to denote an ID selector

Like:

```
$("#CompanySelect")
```

Also can use `this` which will be the `<select>` element inside the change event handler

```
var ProgramValue = $("#Program").val();
var sCompany = $(this).val();
```

After that `remote:{...}` is invalid syntax and you seem to have left out the ajax code for it